# Find where in document user clicked in Visual Studio Extension Context Menu

Tags: c#, vsix, vspackage, visual-studio-extensions

I want to be able to find where the user clicked in the document to bring up the right click context menu. Basically i want to be able to see the exact position of the cursor under the click.

I am handling the right click menu item with the following code, however the eventArgs im using dont have any detail on what the menu was triggered on. Ideally i want to be able to pinpoint how far through the code the user clicked.

```
private void MenuItemCallback(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DTE dte = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(DTE)) as DTE ;
    TextDocument activeDoc = dte.ActiveDocument.Object() as TextDocument;

    var text = activeDoc.CreateEditPoint(activeDoc.StartPoint).GetText(activeDoc.EndPoint);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ActivePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/envdte.textselection.activepoint%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) can be used to deal with most cases:

```
activeDoc.Selection.ActivePoint
```

This will get the active point clicked, but it may give different results if the area clicked is already part of a selection.